# Subquery/CTE executed multiple time?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

The query plan shows that the CTE `s` are executed multiple times (two times in the example. It depends how many times it's used).

```
create view V 
as
with s as (select max(A) A from AExpensiveView)
select count(*) 
from   T, s
where  T.A between s.A and s.A + 100
```

Is it a way to make it executes only one time? It should be in a view or inline function so variable cannot be used.

Comment: Not sure what you mean that the cte is execute multiple times??? There is nothing here other than a view definition. BTW, I would recommend being explicit about using a cross join. You could make this an inline table valued function but not sure if that is what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative to a CTE in this scenario that might help SQL server execute only once.  Hard to know for sure without knowing what SQL server is working with.  It does what it thinks is best, reguardless of how you write your query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM T
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        MAX(A) AS A,
        MAX(A) + 100 AS B
    FROM s
) S ON T.A BETWEEN S.A AND S.B;
```

Comment: Just tried. It has the similar execution plan and IO.

Comment: Have you tried just running the inner query, it might be running multiple times because of the contents of the view itself.